# progressbar not moving

Tags: android, progress-bar

i've an audio app that plays/records samples. i've put a progressbar on the UI but when the sample is played the bar does not move or seem to increment with the sample. how do i get it to move?

```
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            // final long trackDuration = (musicLength/44100)*1000; // track duration in millisec

             // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     //Log.i("music length = ", trackDuration+"");

                     while (mProgressStatus < musicLength) {
                         mProgressStatus = audioTrack.write(music, 0, musicLength);

                         // Update the progress bar
                         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

                             }
                         });
                     }
                 }
             }).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hakan suggests, you need to perform all UI updates in the UI thread.  Since you already have a `Handler`, you just need to override the `handleMessage()` method and perform your UI update there.  Your code would become something like:

```
private static final int PROGRESS_UPDATE = 0;
...
mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
// final long trackDuration = (musicLength/44100)*1000; // track duration in millisec

// Start lengthy operation in a background thread
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //Log.i("music length = ", trackDuration+"");

        while (mProgressStatus < musicLength) {
            mProgressStatus = audioTrack.write(music, 0, musicLength);

            // Update the progress bar
            Message msg = Message.obtain();
            msg.what = PROGRESS_UPDATE;
            msg.arg1 = mProgressStatus;
            mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
}).start();
...
Handler mHandler = new Handler(){
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what){
        case PROGRESS_UPDATE:
            mProgress.setProgress(msg.arg1);
            break;
        default:
            Log.e("MyTag","Unsupported message type");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ok thanks for that dave.c. I've changed from steaming mode to static. I've also written the data to the track before calling play on the track. i've called play in the runnable that handles the progress bar update. the app plays the audio sample but the progress bar still doesnt move. I'll post the code below that shows the ammendments. any ideas to why the progressbar is not moving?

```
// Get the length of the audio stored in the file (16 bit so 2 bytes per short)
        // and create a short array to store the recorded audio.
        musicLength = (int)(file.length()/2);
        final short[] music = new short[musicLength];
        Log.i("filename length", file.length()+""+file.getName());

        try {



        // Create a DataInputStream to read the audio data back from the saved file.
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

        // Read the file into the music array.
        int i = 0;
        while (dis.available() > 0) {
        //music[musicLength-1-i] = dis.readShort();
          music[i] = dis.readShort();

        i++;
        }
        Log.i("buffer with "+ file.getName(), music.length+" passed in from array");

        // Close the input streams.
        dis.close();


        // Create a new AudioTrack object using the same parameters as the AudioRecord
        // object used to create the file.
        audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
        44100,
        AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
        AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
        musicLength,
        AudioTrack.MODE_STATIC);

        Log.i("audio instance = ", ""+audioTrack.getState());

        // Start playback
        //audioTrack.play();






             mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            // final long trackDuration = (musicLength/44100)*1000; // track duration in millisec

             // Start lengthy operation in a background thread
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                     //Log.i("music length = ", trackDuration+"");

                     while (mProgressStatus < musicLength) {

                         mProgressStatus = audioTrack.write(music, 0, musicLength);

                         // Update the progress bar
                         mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                             public void run() {
                                 audioTrack.play();
                                 mProgress.setProgress(mProgressStatus);


                             }
                         });

                         Message msg = Message.obtain();
                         msg.what = PROGRESS;
                         msg.arg1 = mProgressStatus;
                         mHandler.sendMessage(msg);





                     }
                 }
             }).start();

             mHandler = new Handler(){
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                        switch(msg.what){
                        case PROGRESS:
                            mProgress.setProgress(msg.arg1);

                            break;
                        default:
                        Log.e("MyTag","Unsupported message type");
                            break;
                        }

                    }

             };




        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("AudioTrack","Playback Failed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: @ dave.c hi, my Handler is a private field in my UI thread but it atill doesn't work. shouldn't mhandler.sendMessage and mHandler.post(new Runnable() do the same thing, (update the ui thread through the handler)? i swear i've read before that progressbar does noy work well with streaming like in the audiotrack class i use to play the pcm file? any ideas, thanks

Comment: @turtleboy I think you are right.  From a quick google it seems that `AudioTrack#write()` blocks while it has data in its buffer.  As such you are not going to get to any code that occurs after the call to `write`.

Comment: @dave.c ok cool, have you got any suggestions that i could look into?

Comment: @turtleboy no, sorry, I'm not familiar with `AudioTrack` or its use.

Comment: @turtleboy I found [this link](http://code.google.com/p/rxwen-blog-stuff/source/browse/trunk/android/streaming_audio/src/rmd/media/StreamingAudio/Main.java). You might be able to use a similar approach.

Comment: @turtleboy please don't edit answers to ask new questions, it just confuses everyone.  That said, we have already been over the fact that `write()` will block while it has content in its buffer.  Further you are not using `AudioTrack` in streaming mode, you are using `MODE_STATIC`, so the call to `write` will just block until the file has finished playing until the end.

Comment: ok, maybe i'm missing something here, but the only difference between static and streaming is that you call play() first then write the data to the track when streaming, whereas in static mode you write the data to the track then call play(). so in static mode the write has already taken place so no block, then play is called with the progressbar update.

Comment: @turtleboy except with static your buffer has to hold the full file, whereas streaming you can add to the buffer a bit at a time.  If you are adding to the buffer a bit at a time then this gives you an opportunity to update the progress bar in your loop.

Comment: So would you say that it's possible to do this in static mode? It's just you said before that the write is blocking, presumably you meant in both modes. I'm just wondering if audiotrack is not suitable, I've been looking at media.mediaplayer instead, if this can't be implemented

Comment: @turtleboy I can't see a way to get the progress bar to work in static mode, but it is probably possible in stream mode.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) insted of juggling with Threads and Handlers. It contains needed threads and handler method. `onProgressUpdate` is a called in UI thread (after every `publishProgress` call)  so it can update your progress bar successfuly.

Answer (score 0):

you need to update the progress bar in the UI Thread (which is the main Activity Class thread) and not through other threads. You need to create a Handler in the UI thread and send messages to this Handler by your other threads. Android has an example of this when they  [create a ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog). Be sure to expand the section at the bottom which shows an "Example ProgressDialog with a second thread" as this explains my answer with the example.